# HTML tables not showing up after running Python code

Tags: python, html, list, csv, dictionary

My Code is not running somehow. I'm trying to create a table that has the min, max, and average score from 5 tests in my csv file. (my columns the tests and min, max, and average the rows.)

I'm also trying to make a table for the names of students that can be found in the same csv file I'm using. The formatting I want to use is : Last name, first name, average, min and max.

Then lastly I want to determine which student has the highest average and print their name along with their score, outside of the tables.

Here's a sample for my csv file:

| Jailen McQueen | 89 | 30 | 70 | 71 | 26 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cay Phillip | 90 | 10 | 86 | 3 | 50 |
| Gerry Green | 87 | 70 | 40 | 90 | 55 |

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv 
import webbrowser 

csvFile = open('testdata (1).csv') #opens csv file
csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=";") 

test1 = [] 
test2 = []
test3 = []
test4 = []
test5 = []

n = {}

for i in csvReader:
   test1.append(int(i[1]))
   test2.append(int(i[2]))
   test3.append(int(i[3]))
   test4.append(int(i[4]))
   test5.append(int(i[5]))
   n[1[0]] = 1[1:]
csvFile.close()

testNames = {}

for v in n.keys():
    tests = n[x]
    tests = [int(a)for b in tests]
    minimum = min(tests)
    maximum = max(tests)
    mean = sum(tests)/float(len(tests))
    f = x.split()[0]
    l = x.split()[1]
    testNames[f+", "+l] = [mean, minimum, maximum]

html = open('lab3.html','w') 
html.write('<html>\n<body>\n<h1>Test data</h1>\n<ul>\n') #starts creating the table 
html.write('<table border=‘1’><tr><td><td>Test 1</td><td>Test 2</td><td>Test 3</td><td>Test 4</td><td>Test 5</td></tr>\n')
           

csvFile.close() 
html.close
webbrowser.open_new_tab('lab3.html')
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: did you forget the parentheses after `html.close`? currently it looks like the `close()` function is never called and your HTML file won't get written to disk

Comment: also I'm not sure what this line means `n[1[0]] = 1[1:]` Why is it indexing into `1`? There's also a typo in `tests = [int(a)for b in tests]`. Maybe you meant `[int(a) for a in tests]`? Finally it doesn't look like you're using `testNames` anywhere. You should probably build the rest of the HTML table using that.

Comment: if you would use `pandas.DataFrame` then you could use `.to_html()`